# Redirect index.php with parameters to a folder and remove parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I have searched but cannot find a specific answer for this exact redirect style...

I have this structure of URL with this specific parameter:

https://websitename.com/directory/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart

I want it redirected to:

https://websitename.com/shopping-cart/

Note that the above mentioned "directory" changes, but the index.php with the parameters stay the same. No matter what the directory is, I always want it to go to the same exact redirect.

I cannot seem to get the right redirect working in htaccess. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as your **first rule** in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /shopping-cart/? [L,R=308]

# remaining rules go below this
```

Comment: While this works to redirect the page to /shopping cart/ my ajax functions on that page stop working if I use this. Any idea why? For instance, removing an item from the cart is an ajax function and it doesn't work with that code in my htaccess... If I remove the code it works fine.

Comment: What URL are you using for AJAX call? Are you using POST? Also try my updated code from new browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set like this. It takes care on the **param** `view=cart`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=cart
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shopping-cart/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

If you want to keep the querystring params, then change

```
/shopping-cart/?
```

to

```
/shopping-cart/
```

without questionmark